# Rails Multiple Parent Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Three models:

```
User
List
Item
```

A `User` can have many `Lists` and a `List` can have many `Items`. Each `List` can have an `Item` added to it by ANY `User`. This means, for example, that you can create a list and I can add items to it. Make sense? Let's keep going.

I want to be able to find all `Items` created by X `User` at any point in time.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_many :items
end
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I don't like this. It has a funky smell but I can't put my finger on it. I feel like there should be something better. When creating a new `Item` I would have to write something that looks like the following:

```
list = List.find(params[:list_id])
@item = list.items.new(params[:item])
user = User.first
@item.user = user
@item.save!
```

So, what am I missing? Are my relationships wrong (very likely)? Tell me! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there can be *two* different relationships between items and users: 1) `items` are added to `lists` by `users`, and 2) `lists` are created by `users`.

Only one user can create a list. Many users can add items to lists after they are created.

So modeling this requires two different relationships

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_many :items_added, :class_name => "Item", :foreign_key => "added_by_user_id"
end
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :added_by_user, :class_name => "User",  :foreign_key => "user_id"
end
```

It makes sense to assume that you all these relationships are required -- that is, a list needs a user_id when it's created to show who created it. Likewise, an item needs to record who added it to the list.

You'd need to add the `added_by_user_id` column to your `items` table to make this work and keep track of which user added the item.

So you could do this:

```
# To create a user and a list is easy!
user = User.create(user_params)
list = user.create_list(list_params)

# but when adding an item, you need to know which user is adding it
item = list.create_item({:added_by_user => current_user, :item_name => 'name', etc})
```

Now you can find all items added by a user using:

```
all_user_items = user.items_added
```

I haven't tested this and it's a bit complicated so I may have 1-2 mistakes in the code, but generally that's one way this could be modeled.

Comment: i like this, but i think the OP wants to save which user added which item.

Comment: If the solution is like yours, i would add in the User model this line: `has_many :items, :through => :lists`, so he could do: user.items directly.

Comment: Ah. I see. My solution does not capture which user added the item as it is. Let me revisit it.

Comment: I've modified my answer to take into account your points. Better?

Comment: @Kaeros If I do `has_many :items, :through => :lists` then it shows ALL items within those lists, even if the `user_id` is `nil`.